# hosting multiple websites on a single VM securely

Tags: web-application, web-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a server to host a multiple web application, I've done some research and found the hypervisor is the solution but i think it will generate some issues because VM hypervisor on a VM ! so what other solutions do i have to deploy websites securely and if one of these sites is vulnerable will it affect other sites.

Note: I do not own these sites, so i don't know what security measures the developer consider.

Comment: *"I've done some research and found the hypervisor is the solution.."* - A hypervisor is not per se needed to deploy multiple websites on a single server.  *"I do not own these sites,"* - then how can you manage these sites if you don't own these? I think your question is currently focusing too much on a possible solution but is not providing enough background about the problem you are trying to solve. Especially it is unclear what kind of management capability to you have over the applications which should run on the same server and what technologies these require by their own.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I'm trying to create a Hosting service, so other can host their web-application on my server. my main question is how can i deploy multiple web-apps on a single VM with the same IP without securely so if one vulnerable site got compromised it will not affect the others

Comment: There is only a limited security you can offer. There are container technologies (docker, lxc...) which provide some but not all of the isolation a VM offers (which itself offers only part of the isolation you have when using different hardware). Especially containers don't protect against kernel vulnerabilities (like Meltdown but there are also often others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use container technology like Docker (see Steffen Ullrich's comment) to separate them from each other. They still share a kernel (the one of the host machine) but cannot access files stored in other containers or the host system, unless explicitly configured.

You setup could be as follows:

You server as the host machine, running a container software and a reverse proxy. Every web application is hosted in a different container and your host machine's reverse proxy forwards incoming requests to their destination (one of the hosted web apps).

Assume hosted web applications A and B, where their hostnames are a.com and b.com. Both are isolated in their containers. Their HTTP port is bound to some port P(A) and P(B) of your host machine respecively. You host machines HTTP port is said reverse proxy, forwarding connections for a.com to P(A) and b.com to P(B).

This is very basic and can be massivly improved, I'm sure.